# How to add click event in flutter listview..?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have implemented a ListView through FutureBuilder ...i m having question that where to put code for list click item in....

Here is my `FutureBuilder`:

```
new FutureBuilder < List < City >> (
    future: fetchCountry(new http.Client()),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
      return snapshot.hasData ?
        new CityList(city: snapshot.data) :
        new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
  ),
```

And ere is my `list.dart` file:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new ListView.builder(
    itemCount: city == null ? 0 : city.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return
      new Card(
        child: new Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
          child: new Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: new Row(
                // Stretch the cards in horizontal axis
                //       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: < Widget > [
                  new CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    radius: 15,
                    child: new Image.network(city[index].icon.isEmpty ? "https://www.lightlinksolutions.com/tollfreeadmin/images/ic_cat.png" : city[index].icon)
                    //           child:new Image.asset('images/launcher_icon.png')
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: new Text(
                      // Read the name field value and set it in the Text widget
                      city[index].cat_name,
                      softWrap: true,
                      // set some style to text
                      style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
                    ),
                  ),
                  /*    new Text(
                        // Read the name field value and set it in the Text widget
                        "Category:- " + city[index].cat_name,
                        // set some style to text
                        style: new TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.amber),
                      )*/
                ],
              ),
            )),
        ),
      );
    });
}
```

Comment: Please add your list item

Comment: do you want it for list item or the ListView

Comment: I want to put click for listitem and open new screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to add a click event when you tap on a certain item you can wrap the content you want to be pressed on with the following inkwell.

```
 InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        model.selectProduct(product.productID);
        Navigator.pushNamed<bool>(
                context, '/product/' + model.getSelectedProduct.productID)
            .then((_) => model.selectProduct(null));
      },
      child: //your content here
    ),
  );
```

Comment: where should i put it in list item or inside futurebuilder...?

Answer (score 0):

Add the click listener to each list item in CityList.

Use ListTile for each list item. Or if you want to implement your own design, you can use an Inkwell or a GestureDetector.

All of the above will give you access to an `onTap` callback.

Example

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: city == null ? 0 : city.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return GestureDetector(
              ontap: () {},
              Card(
                  child: new Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                    child: new Center(
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: new Row(
                            children:<Widget>[
                                new CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                radius: 15,
                                child:new Image.network(city[index].icon.isEmpty?"https://www.lightlinksolutions.com/tollfreeadmin/images/ic_cat.png":city[index].icon)
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: new Text(
                                    city[index].cat_name,
                                    softWrap: true,
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
                                    ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
          );
        });
  }
```